# Parsing a path in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, substring

I'm using a URLLoader to load a photo and I want to be able to display the filename of the photo based on the URLLoader's `loaderInfo.url` property.

Given a loader named `photoLoader`, what the string called `fileName` be?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the URLLoader class? That class does not have a loaderInfo property. You probably mean the Loader class.

Comment: LopSae - look at the documentation for the LoaderInfo class. loaderInfo is a property of every loader subclass.

Comment: Can't see a loaderInfo in URLLoader's class doc: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the .url property and split it into an array using the / as the delimiter. Then just grab the last item in that array to get the filename.

Code:

```
var pathArray:Array = photoLoader.url.split('/')

var FileName:String = pathArray[pathArray.length()-1]
```

Comment: This answer is more verbose, but more easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
s:String = "http:/somedomain/someurl/somefilename";
```

You could do

```
fileName = s.split('/').pop()
```

to return the top of the array from splitting the url at '/'

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathArray:Array = photoLoader.url.split('/')

var FileName:String = pathArray[pathArray.length-1]
```

Please note that the keyword "length" is not followed by parenthesis. For arrays, it is not supposed to be a function, it is a property. On the other hand, XML lists can use the length() function.